# is there any way to get all producer's ip for every kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to get the relationship between the producer and consumer of kafka, so is there any way to get all producer's ip for every kafka topic ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this as Kafka does not store any metadata about producers centrally so there is no chance to collect all that information.

Comment: Again, as this information is not stored anywhere you will not be able to get it even if you try to write some code. Unless you build your custom producer registry that all producer follow.

Comment: @icy Cloudera Stream Messaging Manager has something like this, but as mentioned, it requires all producer code to be updated

Comment: I try to open request.log and I find the producer ip in it, but there is no topic's information, my kafka's version is 0.11